Does Psalm 56:8 speak of 'measuring of prayers ' by God?
This question was inspired by another question on the number of times that Zechariah prayed for a child.
We read in Psalm 56:8(NLT):

You keep track of all my sorrows. You have collected all my tears in your bottle.

Now,  let us visualise what the Psalmist speaks of teardrops and bottle. You may be able to count the teardrops of a child who is crying. But what if the child keeps on crying and his teardrops are collected in a bottle ? They can no more be counted, but can only be measured by weight ( say, in milligrams) or by volume (  say, in  millilitre). Let us equate the fervent prayers for example,  of a childless couple, to teardrops. They may have been praying for years on end  --in waking stage and 'in sleep'.  Do they finally reach a stage where their prayers are not counted but are 'measured' by God ? Does Psalm 56:8 give a hint to such a perspective  ?

The idea behind this verse is: God is deeply aware of and compassionate towards our suffering. There's no “measuring of prayers.” Instead, God is attentive to every detail of our pain and our sorrow.
Clarke's Commentary has an interesting note. He notes that collecting tears in a bottle is an ancient custom, where mourners would collect their tears in small bottles as a sign of their grief:

Put thou my tears into thy bottle — Here is an allusion to a very
ancient custom, which we know long obtained among the Greeks and
Romans, of putting the tears which were shed for the death of any
person into small phials, called lacrymatories or urnae lacrymales and
offering them on the tomb of the deceased. Some of these were of
glass, some of pottery, and some of agate, sardonyx, c. A small one in
my own collection is of hard baked clay.

The Psalmist uses this as a metaphor. The point is that God values and remembers every tear we shed. Such is the greatness of God.

He knew that the Lord was aware of his suffering. Here, he describes
God's response as tender and caring. God is depicted as counting David's every move and saving each of his tears. This beautifully depicts the Christian idea that God will ultimately redeem all suffering. According to the Bible, no suffering is "wasted" or
pointless (Romans 8:28). All evil will be punished (Revelation
20:11–15) and all hurt will be made right (Revelation 21:4) for those
who know Christ as Savior (John 3:16, 36). (bibleref)


That has led me to my dictionary where I discover that the noun, 'lachrymator' means 'tear-gas'. And I remember that in classical music, a mournful song is called 'Lachrymoso'! Oh, thanks for providing insight re. that verse which has long touched my heart.

Not so fast - this is highly metaphoric language to convey the idea that:

Heb 4:15 - For we do not have a high priest [Jesus] who is unable to sympathize with our weaknesses, but we have one who was tempted in every way that we are, yet was without sin.
Isa 53:4 - Surely He took on our infirmities and carried our sorrows; yet we considered Him stricken by God, struck down and afflicted.
Ps 139:23 - Search me, God, and know my heart; Put me to the test and know my anxious thoughts;
Psalm 34:18 - The Lord is near to the brokenhearted and saves the crushed in spirit.
Isaiah 43:2 - When you pass through the waters, I will be with you; and when you pass through the rivers, they will not sweep over you. When you walk through the fire, you will not be burned; the flames will not set you ablaze.
Matt 28:20 - ... And surely I am with you always, to the very end of the age.”

Indeed, this was one of the great purposes of Jesus incarnation - to demonstrate that He feels our pain and can sympathies with our humanity, Heb 2:8, 9, 14.
The language of Ps 56:8 is in a similar vein - Jesus is always beside us and feels the same pain we endure, because God is supremely kind and compassionate.

Deut 4:31 - For the LORD your God is a merciful God; He will not abandon you or destroy you or forget the covenant with your fathers, which He swore to them by oath.
Ps 103:8 - The LORD is compassionate and gracious, slow to anger, abounding in loving devotion.
Ps 145:8 - The LORD is gracious and compassionate, slow to anger and abounding in loving devotion.
Joel 2:13 - So rend your hearts and not your garments, and return to the LORD your God. For He is gracious and compassionate, slow to anger, abounding in loving devotion. And He relents from sending disaster.

Benson captures the meaning of Ps 56:8 well -

Put thou my tears into thy bottle; which seems to intimate that the
custom of putting tears into the ampullæ, or urnæ lacrymales, so well
known among the Romans, was more anciently in use among the eastern
nations, and particularly among the Hebrews. These urns were of
different materials, some of glass, some of earth, and were placed on
the sepulchres of the deceased, as a memorial of the distress and
affection of their surviving friends and relations. It will be
difficult to account for this expression of the psalmist but upon this
supposition. If this be allowed when the psalmist prays, Put my tears
into thy bottle, the meaning will be, ‘Let my distress, and the tears
I have shed in consequence of it, be ever before thee; let them excite
thy kind remembrance of me, and plead with thee to grant the relief I
stand in need of.’

